# An explanation on user_save() works

Tags: users

I was writing on a module for drupal and i had to update some fields in the user-object. I first tried this code:

```
$account = user_load($user->uid); // Loading account
$edit = array(
  'gitlab_refresh_token' => $response_data['refresh_token'],
);
user_save($account, $edit);
```

This did not update the the field.

Then i found this code on the Internet:

```
$existingUser = user_load($user->uid);
$existingUser->data['gitlab_refresh_token'] = $response_data['refresh_token'];
user_save((object) array('uid' => $existingUser->uid), (array) $existingUser);
```

This code works. But the question is why?

The documentation for `user_save()` says, that `$edit` just needs to contain an array with key/value pairs of what you want to change and it will be put in the user's data field,
and that is what i did, right?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The first snippet doesn't work because Drupal doesn't use any `'gitlab_refresh_token'` array index, and it doesn't know any field with that name. If you were trying to change the value of a field added with the field UI, the array needs to have a different structure, to be saved.

The second snippet works because Drupal effectively uses that array index, as also said in the documentation.

> Key / value pairs added to the `$edit['data']` will be serialized and saved in the {users.data} column.

```
// Prepopulate $edit['data'] with the current value of $account->data.
// Modules can add to or remove from this array in hook_user_presave().
if (!empty($account->data)) {
  $edit['data'] = !empty($edit['data']) ? array_merge($account->data, $edit['data']) : $account->data;
}
```